# How to verify cpu limit assigned to a docker container?

Tags: docker

According to [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/), in order to limit a container to a certain amount of cpu, we use the parameter `--cpus` when starting the container:

`docker run -it --cpus=".5" ubuntu /bin/bash`

Now that I have the container running, how do I check that limit that was assigned to the container in the first place?

In other words, is there a command that I can run and I can see that `.5` that was assigned to the ubuntu container of the example?

Comment: I am not sure the ".5" is really meaningful in *absolute* terms. A Linux system running on a 0.5 virtual CPU (with high-end i9-7960X processor) at 4GHz might have the same "power" than a Linux system running on a real low-end processor (e.g. i3-8145) running at 2GHz. So I don't think that the question is meaningful. What you really want is some sufficient amount of computer power. How to check if you have enough computer power is a different question

Comment: Hi @BasileStarynkevitch. Thanks for your comment. At this point I'm not really questioning if the value is useful or not. Say that I have some servers running docker containers that were started using the `--cpus` parameter. How do I check what value was passed in the first place? That's what I'm trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can check the field `NanoCpus` in `docker inspect` command.

> Specify how much of the available CPU resources a container can use. For instance, if the host machine has two CPUs and you set --cpus="1.5", the container is guaranteed at most one and a half of the CPUs. This is the equivalent of setting --cpu-period="100000" and --cpu-quota="150000". Available in Docker 1.13 and higher.

In your example, the `NanoCpus` should be `500000000` (0.5 * 100000 * 10000)

Comment: `100000*150000 = (10^5) * (15*10^4) = 15*(10^9)` not `1.5*(10^9)`. Then how is that 1.5 NanoCpus, shouldn't that be 15 NanoCpus?

Comment: NanoCpus: `CPU quota in units of 10^-9 CPUs`. https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerCreate https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/7b9275c0da707b030e62c96b679a976f31f929d3/daemon/daemon_unix.go#L154-L160

Answer (score 9):

The first command to check is [`docker container inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/).

```
docker container inspect <container ID or name>|grep -i cpu
```

With `--format`, you can even extract its value directly if exposed.

Then, at runtime, check [`docker stats`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/) to see if, at runtime, the percentage of the host’s CPU and memory the container is using.

Comment: @Esqarrouth Looking at https://github.com/moby/moby/search?q=cpucount&unscoped_q=cpucount, that means the HostConfig did not detect/report at all CPU resources.

Comment: @Esqarrouth You can see it for instance with a Windows container in https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39622

Comment: The HostConfig did not detect the CPUs in my machine right? Or does this mean my CPU limit is unlimited?

Comment: @Esqarrouth Not sure. But yes, the "Host" reference your machine which hosts Docker.